# Take data from an XML file and put it into a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, c, database, bash, parsing

I'm looking to construct a script that would go through an XML file. Would find specific tags in it, put them in a table and fill the table with specific tags within them. I'm using MySQL 5.1 so loadXML isn't an option and I think that ExtractData() method wont be much use either.. but I don't really know. What would be the best way to go about this?

edit// I know how to do all of this in C except the creating the new tables in a database, how would I do that in C?

Comment: what is the issue with ExtractData().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your edit, using the [MySQL client library](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c.html), you would just use [mysql_query()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-query.html) with the standard [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) syntax.

I'm not quite sure why you are doing it the way you are doing it, but I'm not working on whatever you are working on :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [blog](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2006/03/importing-xml-data-into-mysql-using.html). It will explain you how to do this using ExtraceValue() and also look at [XML Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html).